# Proving that a exponential function is in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functions, continuity, exponential-function

I want to prove that $f(x) \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, or that it is infinitely continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ $$f (x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\exp(\frac{1}{x})& x<0 \\
0 & \, \textrm{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
\right. $$
My first thought is that I basically have a composition of functions that already are in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ because for $x\geq 0$ the function is constant at $0$ and thus differentiable and continnuous. For $x<0$ I know that a exponential function is in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ when a function of the form
$g(x)=a^x$ with $a>0$. And beause $e>0$, the function is differentiable and continuous for $x<1$.
Is this approach correct, if not where do I have to fix my mistakes?

Comment: You need to say something about $x = 0$, because function that is $C^\infty$ on $(-\infty, 0)$ and $[0, \infty)$ doesn't have to be $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb R$ - for example, if you replace $\exp(1/x)$ with $1$, both parts of your solution stay in place, but function isn't even continuous anymore.

Comment: So I'm missing the proof that $f(x)$ is indeed differentiable and continuous at $x=0$, right? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us prove by induction, that $$f^n(x) = \begin{cases}
P_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \cdot \exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), & x < 0\\
0, & x \geq 0
\end{cases}$$
where $P_n(y)$ is polynomial.

Base of induction is true with $P_n(x) = 1$.

Assuming it's true for $n$, for $n + 1$ for $x > 0$ we obviously $f^{n + 1}(x) = 0$. For $x < 0$, we have $f^{n + 1}(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} P'_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) -\frac{1}{x^2} P_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, so we can take $P_{n + 1}(y) = -y^2  \cdot (P'_n(y) + P_n(y))$.

Finally, for $x = 0$ we have $f^{n + 1}(0) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f^n(x)}{x}$. For $x \to 0^+$ this limit is $0$ as function in numerator is just $0$, and for $x \to 0^-$ we have $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} \frac{f^n(x)}{x} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} \frac{P\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot \exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x} = \lim\limits_{y \to +\infty} \frac{-y \cdot P(-y))}{\exp(y)}$$ which is $0$, as exponent growth faster than any polynomial.